# Useful Shortcuts in eclipse to analyse the existing application

Tags: java, eclipse, analysis

I am going to do one enhancement in the existing java project .So I have to learn the useful short cut keys to navigate and analyse the java project in eclipse.

Example :
1 .If I use F3 it will navigate to method where its used
2.Ctrl+o will show the list of methods

Your help is highly appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at a [cheatsheet](https://github.com/pellaton/eclipse-cheatsheet) for the version of eclipse you're using.